# Missing javascript dependency for python-pyinstrument

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, profiling

I am trying to profile a python program with pyinstrument but it keeps throwing this error when trying to render the profile in html.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ananda/projects/product_pred/025200812_cpall_ai_ordering_model_v2/.venv/bin/pyinstrument", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ananda/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument/__main__.py", line 304, in main
    output_filename = renderer.open_in_browser(session)
  File "/home/ananda/projects.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument/renderers/html.py", line 70, in open_in_browser
    f.write(self.render(session))
  File "/home/ananda/projects/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument/renderers/html.py", line 25, in render
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Could not find app.js. If you are running pyinstrument from a git checkout, run 'python setup.py build' to compile the Javascript (requires nodejs).
```

It seems that I don't have nodejs so I tried installing that by `sudo apt install nodejs` but I am getting the same error.

I know the error is asking me to run `python setup.py build` but I don't even have a setup.py file for my repo so I am not sure what that is supposed to do. Am I to run it from the installation folder of pyinstrument or something? I tried going in there but I can't find a setup.py file there as well (under `.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinstrument`)

The file that I am trying to run is a simple script so I don't think that matters.

```
import time

time.sleep(2)
print("hello, world")
```

The way I am running the program is like so -

`pyinstrument -r html src/jobs/evaluator.py`

If I try running pyinstrument without using html rendering, `pyinstrument src/jobs/evaluator.py`, it works but the output is in the terminal and I would really like the html output.

I think I am just missing some javascript dependency here but I am not sure what or how to install it.

I am using the following versions -

```
python 3.8.10
pyinstrument 4.0.0
node v8.10.0
OS - Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of searching, I found a [github issue](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument/issues/137) for `pyinstrument` with the exact same error, and it seems like they fixed it in an update (`4.0.2`). Try updating your pyinstrument version and let me know if it works!

Note: If you do end up getting an error after upgrading to `4.0.2`, in another [github issue](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument/issues/139), the maintainer is working on a fix at the moment, so unfortunately either you'll have to find an earlier version that does work, or you'll have to wait for the developer to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! Strange that this never popped up when I was searching for the issue even though the title is identical to the error message. This was the issue.

Comment: Glad to help out! Best of luck to you with your project.